# R: Perform imputation when column types slightly differ

Tags: r, bigdata, r-caret

Suppose I have a training

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-training.csv

and testing dataset

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/predmachlearn/pml-testing.csv

When I check the data type I see a little difference, for example:

test data (pml-testing):

```
 $ max_roll_dumbbell       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ max_picth_dumbbell      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ max_yaw_dumbbell        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ min_roll_dumbbell       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ min_pitch_dumbbell      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ min_yaw_dumbbell        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ amplitude_roll_dumbbell : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

training data (training subset of pml-training):

```
 $ max_roll_dumbbell       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ max_picth_dumbbell      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ max_yaw_dumbbell        : Factor w/ 73 levels "","0.0","-0.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ min_roll_dumbbell       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ min_pitch_dumbbell      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ min_yaw_dumbbell        : Factor w/ 73 levels "","0.0","-0.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ amplitude_roll_dumbbell : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

As long as data is big I have created the model excluding NA's and insufficient variables:

```
set.seed(614)
library(lattice); library(ggplot2); library(caret)
pml.training <- read.csv("pml-training.csv")
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=pml.training$classe, p=0.9, list=FALSE)
training <- pml.training[inTrain,]
testing <- pml.training[-inTrain,]

##variables with almost no changes
nsv<-nearZeroVar(training,saveMetrics=TRUE)     
nsv

training2<-training[,!(nsv$nzv)]
tr2<-training2[complete.cases(training2),]

### Using additional cores! Remove if you don't have
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores = 4)
###

model1 <- train(classe~.,data=tr2,method="gbm",verbose=FALSE)
print(model1)
```

Now I have used `knnImputation()` to complete data and check my model on testing subset of `pml-training`, it works OK:
(takes some time!):

```
library(DMwR)
testng3<-knnImputation(testing,k=10,distData=training)
predict3 <- predict(model1,testng3)
sum(predict3==testng3$classe)/length(testng3$classe)
## [1] 0.9959184
```

And now I want to use pml-testing data. It's last column is different, so I drop it (the same for `classe` col from `pml-training`) and try to perform `knnImputation()` to complete data from training set:

```
my_pml_testing <- read.csv("pml-testing.csv")
my_pml_testing2<-knnImputation(my_pml_testing[,-length(my_pml_testing)],
    k=10,distData=training[,-length(training)])
```

Error:

> Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Trying to use the raw data with the last column dropped results a lot of errors in variables which I think are caused by NA's:

```
predict4 <- predict(model1,my_pml_testing[,-length(my_pml_testing)])
```

What can I do to apply the model to the test set?

EDIT: The reason why I'm asking is that the [following code](https://github.com/rkackerman/Coursera-Hopkins-Practical-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Practical_Machine_Learning_Project_Ackerman.Rmd) is working (but takes a HUGE resources, so the problem should be with my model).

Comment: Looks like you made an error by not checking your data and not fixing a factor coercion at the data entry steps. Both `max_yaw_dumbbell`  and `min_yaw_dumbbell` started out as numeric and they got entered as factor. I suspect this was data that was collated on Excel because I see "#DIV/0!" in the data. It's not clear what error you made in the "testing" data but there were numbers in there before, so that data entry process was kaput as well. You need to back up 10 steps and redo the data entry completely.

Comment: @42- There are about 160 variables in the dataset and I have no idea how to perform an input that preserves the same data type. The second strange thing that the building and applying model suddenly works [here](https://github.com/rkackerman/Coursera-Hopkins-Practical-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Practical_Machine_Learning_Project_Ackerman.Rmd) (I checked it, but it requires ~6 GB of memory) - the same input method was used.

Comment: @42- This is not my data, all I have are these *.csv files.

Comment: The point is that there is numeric data in those files that is not being properly input into R by the process you are using. You are not ready to ask questions about imputation or classification because you have messed up the data entry at the R stage.

Comment: @42- So how can I input this data properly? There are about 160 variables to check!

Comment: You should be using colClasses to maintain "numeric" data types